# gsub: adding space after punctuation

Tags: r, regex, gsub, punctuation

Let's assume I have the following

```
a <- ".mama"
```

and I would like to obtain the following:

```
". mama"  # one space after .
```

The following is not working:

```
a <- gsub(".m", ". m", a)
```

Could anyone help me with this basic question?

Comment: What language are you trying to use? What does "not working" mean exactly? What is thw result?

Comment: @rici He is using R, and I have updated the tags.  This also explains why a ton of people have not seen this question yet (e.g. @akrun).

Comment: `gsub(".m", ". m", ".mama", fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your replacement is using a literal dot (`.`), which means match any character.  Hence, the character sequence `am` also matches and is replaced by `. m`.  Instead, escape the dot:

```
a <- gsub("\\.m", ". m", a)
[1] ". mama"
```

Alternative by @alistaire

```
a <- gsub(".m", ". m", a, fixed=TRUE)
```

Alternative by @Jota

```
a <- gsub("[.]m", ". m", a)
```